# Linking error with template classes

Tags: c++, templates, g++, function-pointers, functor

I have a class that needs to call an external function in a variety of different contexts.  I want to keep things flexible, so I'm using an interface (inspired by the 3rd edition of Numerical Recipes) that should work with functors, function pointers, etc.  A simplified example looks like:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    template <class T>
    MyClass(T &f_) { f = f_; }
  private:
    int (*f)(int);
};

int myFn(int i) {
  return i % 100;
}

int main() {
  MyClass test(myFn);
  return 0;
}
```

So far so good; g++ compiles this without any complaints.  In my real application, there's a lot more code so I've got things split up among multiple files.  For example,

test2.h:

```
#ifndef __test2__
#define __test2__

class MyClass {
  public:
    template <class T>
    MyClass(T &f_);    
 private:
    int (*f)(int);
};

#endif
```

test2.cpp:

```
#include "test2.h"

template <class T>
MyClass::MyClass(T &f_) {
  f = f_;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "test2.h"

int myFn(int i) {
  return i % 100;
}

int main() {
  MyClass test(myFn);
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this using `g++ test2.cpp main.cpp`, I get the following linking error:

```
/tmp/ccX02soo.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass<int ()(int)>(int (&)(int))'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It appears that g++ isn't aware of the fact that I'm also trying to compile test2.cpp.  Any ideas about what might be going on here?

Thanks,

--craig

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1):

Template classes must have their implementation visible to all translation units that use them, unless they are fully specialized.

That means you have to move the implementation in the header:

```
//test2.h
#ifndef __test2__
#define __test2__

class MyClass {
  public:
    template <class T>
    MyClass(T &f_);    
 private:
    int (*f)(int);
};

template <class T>
MyClass::MyClass(T &f_) {
  f = f_;
}

#endif
```